# Browser only linux distribution

Tags: linux, browser, linux-distributions

I had set up [moodle](https://moodle.org/) server for teaching students at my department. We have 2 computer rooms that are used by students for accessing this server and completing quizzes. Currently all computers have different Windows OSes (from Windows 98 to Windows 7). I want to install linux distibution with browser.

I had set up [BrowserLinux](http://www.browserlinux.com/) (based on latest [Puppy linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm)) it worked fine until someone of students had broke it to unbootable state (default user is root).

Is there any standard solution to my problem?

My requirements are:

- hard disk installation
- no write rights to HDD for default user
- graphical interface
- browser capable of showing [moodle](https://moodle.org/) (JavaScript, and Flash for video lectures)
- all changes made during session returning to default on next boot
- possibility to set home page for browser (moodle server login page)

Comment: Have you looked at [ChromeOS](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/)?

Comment: Have you looked at something like [LTSP](http://www.ltsp.org/)?  This would give you a PXE booted environment, which the students couldn't easily break.  It is pretty easy to setup with Ubuntu Server.

Comment: I had set up LTSP but (1) it allows users to store information on server (2) programs are executed on server side (3) class is connected via wireless bridge (4) not all computers are easy to make it run (different BIOSes and network cards)

Comment: Chome OS is looking good but is it possible to install in on HDD?

Comment: ChromeOS (at least the builds i had found) do not support Ethernet (wired network).

Comment: Just change root password?